# Using Groovy in soapUI to extract a JSON field for use in subsequent steps

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am new to Groovy scripting in soapUI. I'm trying to retrieve response in Groovy and get the content as string and get `trans id` from the response body and use it to set in request2.

Below is the response body.

```
{"trans response" : {
   "status" : "pending request",
   "trans id " : 1000078
  }
}
```

Comment: You have keys with spaces? Ewww.. JsonSlurper is what you need here... What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet extracts the value of `trans id` (trailing space included) and sets a test case property:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.expand('${RESTRequest1#Response}'))
def String transId = response.'trans response'.'trans id '

// Set as a test case property
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("transId", transId)
```

You can then use the `transId` property in subsequent step steps

Comment: Craig's solution is a good one.  Though, I'm not a big fan setting and getting property values.  If I need to pull a value from a previous step into another step, I'd create a Groovy script (e.g. getTransId) as above, but I'd return the value of interest (return transId;).  In the step that I want to put that value into, I can access it by${getTransId#result}.  I'm not saying set and get property value is a bad approach, just highlighting another way.